# How to update CNAME component of DNS using .net?

Tags: .net

Does anyone know how to update CNAME component of DNS using .net?

Comment: .net as in the top-level domain, .net or are you talking about Microsoft .NET Framework?

Comment: It probably also depends on what kind of DNS server you have. If it is an MS server with AD, I assume it is more ".NET (framework)-friendly".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ".net" stands for the .NET framework, I would have a look at [DnsModifyRecordsInSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682012(VS.85).aspx) and use P/Invoke. There is possibly a managed solution, too.